# React Native App Crash in Production

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I recently pushed an update to our React Native app. Everything was running fine, however during the review, Apple rejected the update because the app crashed on boot. I created an Ad-Hoc build and installed the release version on my own device and saw the same behavior. If I run the app in dev mode via XCode, everything works fine.

To create the release build of the app, I would simply archive it on XCode and upload to the app store.

I symbolicated the crash report sent from Apple. Here are the meaningful lines the report:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1812a6364 0x181160000 + 1336164
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1804ec528 0x1804e4000 + 34088
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1812a62ac 0x181160000 + 1335980
3   MyApp                           0x1047c2c24 RCTFatal + 1354788 (RCTAssert.m:134)
4   MyApp                           0x1047c08e8 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatalException:stack:exceptionId:] + 1345768 (RCTExceptionsManager.m:60)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1812adcd0 0x181160000 + 1367248
6   CoreFoundation                  0x18118c56c 0x181160000 + 181612
7   CoreFoundation                  0x18119101c 0x181160000 + 200732
8   MyApp                           0x1047d3d9c -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 1424796 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:537)
9   MyApp                           0x104813abc facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&) + 1686204 (RCTNativeModule.mm:101)
10  MyApp                           0x10481381c invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 1685532 (RCTNativeModule.mm:73)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x180c22a54 0x180c21000 + 6740
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x180c22a14 0x180c21000 + 6676
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x180c2c96c 0x180c21000 + 47468
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x180c2d2fc 0x180c21000 + 49916
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x180c2dd20 0x180c21000 + 52512
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x180c3603c 0x180c21000 + 86076
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x180ecaf1c 0x180eca000 + 3868
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x180ecab6c 0x180eca000 + 2924
```

I don't see much meaning information from this report other than a crash occurred. Am I overlooking something obvious?

Any tips/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just ran into this one myself, haven't figured it out yet.  What version of React Native are you using?

Comment: @adam: Have you got resolution of this issue, I facing same issue!

Comment: @DaveCole: I am using rn 0.59, have found resolution of issue at your end?

Comment: @Sumit whoo boy... this was so long ago that I've forgotten, but I believe I created an entirely new CRA project and copied all my source into it.  Best of luck!

Comment: @Dave Cole: Thanks for responding, I solved it :) The solution comes with most valuable learning in React Native (I need to upgrade native shells also along with react native version :)

Answer (score 0):

Apple will test your application on an iPad, even if your app is build to run on iPhone only.

Maybe you could check if you can reproduce the crash when running it on iPad ?

Comment: Based on crash log it was on an iPhone. I have also been able to produce the crash. The issue if making sense of the crash.